# How to make former 3d buttons look

Tags: button, appearance

Buttons in the latest Mathematica version 13 (and perhaps even a little bit before) have lost their nice embossed look. They now look like simple flat rectangles in their default style.

Is there a way to recover previous look?

I am particularly interested in Win and Mac systems

UPDATE:
@MarcoB mentioned in a comment that the change took place in version 11. Check his comment below.

So can we make current V.13 buttons look like pre-version 11 buttons?

The code that generated the legacy buttons is no longer present in the current version?

Perhaps we can put an image (any image) in the button area. The image should be scalable

Comment: The default appearance for buttons depend on your system theme.  So providing your platform and version will be important.

Comment: @ihojnicki Thank you, edited

Comment: I think you can see the change in version 11. Compare the Button docs [in version 10.4](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v10.4/ref/Button.html) and [in version 11.0](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v11/ref/Button.html).

Comment: Thank you @MarcoB. So my question still stands....can we make Version 13 buttons look like version 10.x buttons?

Answer (score 2):

No.  The default appearance for most of the controls are operating system theme dependent.  For instance:  v6 through v13 will all have the same appearance on Windows 10/11.